# Retrieve custom attributes given to method parameters

Tags: c#, .net

I am employing a logic similar to the suggestion present in the Microsoft documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cs58sb90(v=vs.110).aspx to retrieve the custom attributes given to the parameter of a method.

However, I find this approach expensive as it uses reflection to retrieve the custom attributes, I am wondering if there is any better approach to this problem than using reflection?

Comment: AFAIK, the only way to get attributes values is reflection.

Comment: I don't think that doing reflection is that very expensive. Are you looking at discovering attributes across million of class. Because that i think is expensive. You should read this article.https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/

Comment: 'expensive' is a relative term. What is the purpose of your app? What is you implementation look like?

Comment: @DaniDev Please see the other detailed post on stakoverflow on the problem that I am trying to solve using this approach.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50110535/extract-custom-attribute-value-set-to-the-action-method-parameters

Comment: @ngeksyo I want to execute a custom logic based on the attributes given to the action method parameter in an API method. Since this logic (in turn the reflection) logic would gets executed for every request made to the API method, I feel that this could be an expensive approach.

Comment: If you want to get information about attributes you will need to use reflection

Comment: Anyway just for your information, i did 1000 custom attribute lockups in 4 millisecond or on average 0.004 ms per lookup, averaged over 100 runs

Answer (score 1):

The short answer as far as I am aware is no, reflection is the standard and probably only way to retrieve attributes.

However, attributes are fixed in the type metadata at compile-time, which means you will only ever have to inspect them once for each type during the lifetime of your program, and they won't change in that time unless your code is doing some really wacky runtime type construction (e.g. with `Reflection.Emit`). Even if you don't know the exact type of any object your code requires the attributes of, you could still cache the type's attributes in a dictionary to save looking them up again, if you're really that concerned about performance.

Comment: Thank you Tom - sounds like a solution to me , I will give it a go.